# OQL in Eclipse memory analyzer - how to display array / ArrayList contents

Tags: java, eclipse, oql

I have a dump which I opened with Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

I would like to export some contents of the heap into a file.

One of the fields I'm interested in is an `ArrayList` and I could not find a way to query the dump in a way that will return the **contents** of the array list as an output:

- Selecting the ArrayList object itself returns something like:
  `java.util.ArrayList [id=0xf2765680]`
- Selecting the array within the
  array list (`select arr.elementData...`) returns something like:
  `java.lang.Object[] [id=0xf2765698;length=4]`
- Selecting `toString(arr)` or `toString(arr.elementData)` returns empty string when the arrayList isn't null (and the string `null` when it is).

Is it really impossible??

Answer (score 8):

To get list of elements

```
SELECT OBJECTS arr.@referenceArray FROM OBJECTS <your_array_address> arr
```

To re-map list of elements of array

```
SELECT OBJECTS elem.<field_name> FROM OBJECTS (SELECT OBJECTS arr.@referenceArray FROM OBJECTS <your_array_address> arr) elem
```

Real example

```
SELECT OBJECTS elem.callable.task.task FROM OBJECTS (SELECT OBJECTS arr.@referenceArray FROM OBJECTS 0x645eb6b80 arr) elem
```

Comment: Perfect! 3Q~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today with an array. I could not find a way to do this using OQL, but I did find a way using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer itself.

1. Select the parent object of the data you want to export. Your collection should now show in the Attributes tab on the left of the screen.
2. Right click the collection in the Attributes list and select *Copy - Save Value to File* or *Copy - Value*.
3. If you choose *Save Value to File*, specify the file location. The contents of the collection will be output to the file.

Alternatively there appears to be an option to extract the values in a list.

1. Right click the list.
2. Select *Java Collections - Extract List Values*.

I have not attempted the second option but I hope this helps you or anyone else searching this topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the options worked for me.
Besides, extracting each list by itself is not an option for me because I had hundreds of array lists which I wanted to extract. I ended up with a query looks like `select arrList.elementData[0].toString(), arrList.elementData[1].toString(), ...` going on up to the size of the biggest array list I had. Ugly, but provided what I needed. Thanks.